# Opening a dialog in jquery always prompt do you want to save this file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

if i try to open a dialog in jquery, it does opens dialog but it prompt save as file. And forces me to download a txt file which has no data in it.

How to prevent that file download option. Here is my code.

```
        var dialogDiv = $("#DialogTest");
        dialogDiv.dialog(
            {
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 450,
                position: 'center',
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                title: 'name',
                buttons: {
                    'Ok': function () {

                    }
                                    ,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                open: function () {
                    $("#name").removeClass("invalidInput").focus();

                },
                close: function () {

                }
            });


       $("#Button").bind("click", function () {

            dialogDiv.dialog('open');

        });


//Html code

    <div id="DialogTest">
            <legend id="name"></legend>
            <label for="name">Enter Name<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="LongInputField" maxlength="50" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Running this on JsFiddle works as expected? http://jsfiddle.net/PhyL3/

Comment: This code is working fine, thanks